# What is the probability of a biased coin being part of a cluster of length L?

Tags: probability

So I have an infinite sequence of biased coin flips, probability $p$ for heads.

A cluster of length $L$ is defined as a sequence of $L$ consecutive heads, given that at both ends there is a tail.

What is the probability that, by picking a coin from this infinite sequence, it is a part of a cluster of length $L$?

Edit: The sequence is infinite in both directions. I tried this. When choosing a coin, for it to be part of a cluster, it has to firstly be heads. The probability for that is $p$. Then for it to be part of a cluster $L$ the sequence of heads has to extend to the right by $a$ and to the left by $b$, with $a+b+1=L$. This gives the total probability of $p^L$, which is the same as the probability of finding a cluster of length $L$.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Does the sequence have a beginning? That is, is there a first coin flip, or is it infinite in both directions?

Comment: @Dasherman Does it matter?  If the sequence has a beginning, the probability that the coin chosen is one of the first $L$ is $0$, so we can just ignore that possibility, can't we?

Comment: @saulspatz I interpreted the question as being about picking a fixed coin. If we choose a coin randomly, we need some distribution over this sequence.

Comment: @Dasherman Yes, I think you're right.  I was just thinking you get the same probability for any coin after the first $L$, but there's no a priori way to ignore the first $L$, unless as you suggest, the sequence is infinite in both directions.

Comment: Assume you mean that the sequence is indexed by a doubly infinite sequence, and as you mentioned, for a particular chosen coin, it can be any one of the $L$ locations in the cluster. So the event of interest is the union of these events. And if you restrict the both end to be tail (i.e. the length is exactly $L$ but not larger), you are actually observing the results of $L+2$ coins, and they will be mutually exclusive in such case, and we will have $Lp^L(1-p)^2$. See if the assumption match.

Comment: @BGM I was thinking of adding the end tails, but I don't know why you also have the $L$ term in front.